# How to use context.read in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-provider

I am using the provider package as my state management solution for my Flutter app. I want to call context.read() after making an API call to Firestore using the FutureBuilder widget. However, according to Provider's documentation, I can't do that:

> It's worth noting that context.read() won't make a widget rebuild when the value changes and it cannot be called inside StatelessWidget.build/State.build. On the other hand, it can be freely called outside of these methods.

How then should I go about doing that if I can't call context.read() it in the build method?

I asked ChatGPT and it tells me to use addPostFrameCallback and this seems to have solved the above issue.

```
return FutureBuilder(
      future: getUserInfoFromFirestore,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          // get data from Firestore           
          final data = snapshot.data.data() as Map<String, dmynamic>;          
          final String userName = data['name'];
          WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
            // the following line is same as using context.read  
            Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false).name = userName;
          }); 
      }
```

However, i have noticed that the setter in my UserProvider is being called again and again.
Here is the code for UserProvider:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  String _name = '';
  String _status = '';
  String _avatar = '';

  String get name => _name;
  String get status => _status;
  String get avatar => _avatar;

  set name(String newVal) {
    _name = newVal;
    debugPrint('name setter called');
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set status(String newVal) {
    _status = newVal;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set avatar(String newVal) {
    _avatar = newVal;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Will this cause an issue in the future? Is there another way to set the provider? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "it cannot be called inside StatelessWidget.build/State.build" where did you get that from? There's no problem in calling `context.read` within `build`

Comment: okay, I see it's in `provider` package README. I'm almost sure it's incorrect though and you're perfectly fine (technically) calling `context.read` from within `build` methods